# Use fingerprint in apps but not device unlock

Tags: lock-screens, fingerprint, fairphone-4

On my Samsung Galaxy A14, I could configure my fingerprint for use within apps (such as banking and qualified electronic signature apps) but not for unlocking my phone. This is my preferred setup as I do not want to be able to unlock my phone solely with a fingerprint.

However, on my new Fairphone 4, which runs a closer-to-stock version of Android 13, I can't seem to locate an option for this. Surely, there must be a way to achieve this, **somehow**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a permanent workaround, **3rd-party apps can "disable" fingerprint unlock by force-locking the system and requiring strong authentication (PIN, pattern, or password) to unlock the device.** Note that this requires the app to be registered as a device administrator to leverage the feature.

1. [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm)

   [image]

   - **Profile**: Event - Display - Display Off
   - **Task**: Display - System Lock
2. [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate)

   [image]

   1. Add new block: **Interface** - **Display on?**
   2. Connect **Flow beginning (GO)** to **When display on (IN)**
   3. Connect **When display on (YES)** to **When display on (IN)**
   4. Add new block: **Interface** - **Device lock**
   5. Connect **When display on (NO)** to **Lock device (IN)**
   6. Connect **Lock device (OK)** to **When display on (IN)**

Comment: Thanks! Works like charm. Now that you mention it, I vaguely remember having a similar setup on one of my even older phones.

Answer (score 2):

There's an [old Android Device Admin API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#KEYGUARD_DISABLE_FINGERPRINT) for disabling fingerprints on the lockscreen, which, [while deprecated](https://developers.google.com/android/work/device-admin-deprecation), continues working even on Android 14 as long as the app accessing that API targets at most API28.

Somebody wrote an app for toggling that API and [**it's available on F-Droid**](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.davidshewitt.admincontrol/).

Answer (score 0):

**On stock Android (AOSP), it doesn't seem to be possible to customize how fingerprints should be used, other than the default for unlocking the device and additionally for biometric authentication.**

[A YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BsWT-6m34ww) by the official Fairphone channel shows that the interface is the same as AOSP, where there is no customization other than adding, removing, or renaming the fingerprints. (Cross-checked with Google Pixel 3a on stock Android 12; [additional reference](https://support.google.com/pixelphone/thread/78853645/pixel-3a-how-to-disable-fingerprint-unlock-without-deleting-prints)).

For these devices, the standard way to disable fingerprint unlock is [to delete all the fingerprints](https://support.google.com/pixelphone/answer/6285273?hl=en#zippy=%2Cstop-using-delete-fingerprints). For temporary workaround, [activate Lockdown mode if available](https://www.zdnet.com/article/how-to-use-the-android-lockdown-mode-and-why-you-should/), but this always needs to be re-activate on each unlock.

---

As for Samsung devices, they actually [made customization](https://www.samsung.com/us/support/answer/ANS00082563/) to the Android OS to add the "Fingerprint unlock" toggle and other settings. (Confirmed on Galaxy M12, Android 13).

> - **Fingerprint unlock**: Unlocks your device when your fingerprint is recognized.